# I destroyed my Mac's PHP setup: SSL certification fails

Tags: php, ssl

Long story short, I deleted the PHP symlink on my Mac, and replaced it with a symlink from XAMPP. Now it seems that there's a problem with my SSL configuration or what seems to me, a lack thereof.

For example, when I run `composer self-update` it throws this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                       
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed                                              
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                        
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I got [this debug script](http://pastebin.com/2tfqjQ2z) from somewhere and it says:

Bool(false)
String(69) "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
String(0) ""

It looks like curl.cainfo is unset from the php.ini

Curlerror.txt says:

```
* About to connect() to extensions.bolt.cm port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 46.17.0.55...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x100976400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x100976400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to extensions.bolt.cm (46.17.0.55) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
```

So any ideas on how to fix this? Should I just set the curl.cainfo in php.ini (or somewhere) and point it to a my certs location? Where is that location?

Comment: Perhaps better suited for general computing?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: http://superuser.com/